# Importing data into Apache Solr from Cassandra using dataimporthandler

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-jdbc

Is it possible to import data from Cassandra into Apache Solr?

I am currently importing data from MySQL into Apache Solr using Solr's dataimporthandler. Is it possible to use Cassandra in place of MySQL?

**Update 1:**

I tried to connect to Cassandra from a simple Java program using the JDBC driver given here (https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/). My idea was, if the java code works, Solr should also be to import from Cassandra. But it didn't work and I got the following error:

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/cql/jdbc/AbstractJdbcType
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.(CassandraConnection.java:146)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:92)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at CqlConnection.main(CqlConnection.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.AbstractJdbcType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more

Comment: Could you figure out integrating the latest versions without datastax?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer - Never tried this, so cannot vouch for performance etc :)

Solr's DataImportHandler contrib uses JDBC to connect to a relational data source. Here is the official Solr Wiki about [configuring JDBC](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Configuring_JdbcDataSource)

Now, for Cassandra, you could use the [Cassandra-jdbc](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/) driver and setup your DIH config to have SQL that this driver supports.

Please note:
- I have not used Cassandra-jdbc in a production setup, so there might be shortcomings that you may want to consider piloting on.
- As mentioned above, I do not know the performance aspect as well - will recommend you spike it out.

Please post back any findings!

Comment: Cassandra-jdbc is too old and it supports only older versions of cassandra. Currently, the java-cassandra is provided by [Datastax](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver). I don't think this can be used with Solr. Datastax have their own package of solr and cassandra integrated. But that is a paid version.